# How can I represent a reference to an enum with a statically known variant?

Tags: rust

I have the following situation (simplified/toy example to focus on the main parts)

- I have a datatype with two possible representations, which I represent as two enum variants
- I have one part of my system producing Boxed instances of this datatype. It produces some arbitrary mixture of the two variants - I don't yet statically know which variant.
- I have various downstream parts of my system that consume these instances. Each such downstream component *must* be given either one form or the other, depending on the component.
- the instances are passed by owned reference (i.e. Box), and freed by those downstream components
- I have functions to convert to each specific variant, but these conversions must happen *in place* - reallocation into a new Box is not ok.

Here is some code with concrete examples of what doesn't work

```
struct XY(i32, i32);
struct LengthAndAngle(i32, i32);

enum Point2D {
    XY(XY),
    LengthAndAngle(LengthAndAngle)
}

impl Point2D {

    // ideally typed as
    // fn convertToXY(self) -> Self::XY
    fn convertToXY(self) -> Self {
        if let Self::LengthAndAngle(LengthAndAngle(length, angle)) = self {
            Self::XY(XY(todo!(), todo!()))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }

    fn convertToLengthAndAngle(self) -> Self {
        if let Self::XY(XY(x, y)) = self {
            Self::LengthAndAngle(LengthAndAngle(todo!(), todo!()))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

fn producer() -> Box<Point2D>;

// Four versions of the function that don't work.

// This is what I want, but it's illegal in Rust
fn consumer1(pointXY: Box<Point2D::XY>);
fn consumer2(pointLengthAndAngle: Box<Point2D::LengthAndAngle>);
// this is legal in Rust but requires reallocation
fn consumer1(pointXY: Box<XY>);
fn consumer2(pointLengthAndAngle: Box<LengthAndAngle>);
// this is legal in Rust but doesn't allow taking ownership and freeing the Point2D
fn consumer1(pointXY: &mut XY);
fn consumer2(pointLengthAndAngle: &mut LengthAndAngle);
// this is legal is Rust but doesn't allow me to statically enforce the variant.
fn consumer1(pointXY: Box<Point2D>);
fn consumer2(pointLengthAndAngle: Box<Point2D>);


fn main() {
    let mut point1 = producer();
    let mut point2 = producer();
    
    *point1 = point1.convertToXY();
    consumer1(point1);
    
    *point2 = point2.convertToLengthAndAngle();
    consumer2(point2);
}
```

same code on rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3caea7c9475584a23ca60adb116c0d5

Comment: Why are the boxes even necessary here? The idiomatic way to do this in Rust would be to have the functions accept `XY` and `LengthAndAngle` directly. No reference, no box.

Comment: The conversion functions should likewise return these types instead of `Self`.

Comment: @cdhowie the Box is necessary in my real application for reasons that have been simplified out of this example (but it's an absolute requirement). I realize that if that weren't a requirement that this would be trivial.

Comment: As for the conversion functions, they would *ideally* return an enum-variant type, e.g. `Self::XY`, but that can't be expressed in current rust. Note that if they returned the inner types, e.g. plain `XY`, then the in-place conversion `*point1 = point1.convertToXY()` would not work.

Comment: Sure it would. `*point1 = Point2D::XY(point1.convertToXY())` is perfectly idiomatic Rust for exactly this situation.

Comment: sure, unfortunately none of that is helpful though :/

Comment: @ajp The confusion comes from the fact that it's not very clear, why you want `Box<Point2D::XY>`, instead of just using `XY`. Is it because you're actually looking for something like `Box<dyn Into<XY>>`, i.e. allowing to consume/produce _anything_ that can be converted into `XY`?

Comment: I suppose you *could* wrap your `Box<Point2D>` in a type together with a `PhantomData<T>` where `T` is the inner type of the variant... but there's probably a much Better Way to solve your underlying problem than the approach you're asking about here.

Comment: @ajp _Why_ isn't it helpful? You're working against the grain here. All you need to do is have your conversion functions return the inner types instead of an enum value, but you haven't articulated why that is not a valid solution. It is _the_ idiomatic way to do this in Rust.